# The checkbox 'Define Automatic Routing rules' should be enabled only if 'Configuration Name' and 'Supplier' are selected

Tags: java, microservices

needs to be get logic on back-end side.

configuration name and supplier name should be select any entry in drop-down item,

after that needs to check button define automatic routing rule.

after clicking automatic routing rule configuration name should be see like 'list Automatic 1', 'list Automatic 2 and so on.

so there are add,edit endpoints created in back-end.

so my question is automaticRoutingRules is defined in string in model class?

where i need to changed?

i am trying automaticRoutingRules define as a array in model ,

we are expecting For example if the Configuration Name is 'Standard_Provide', the automatic configuration name will be 'Standard_Provide Automatic 1'and so on.